# I can't find launcher on my apps

Tags: launcher

I cant find it in the drawer. I've been experiencing errors and I've found the solution. Problem is, my launcher is missing and I cant clear the data because I can't find it.

Comment: (1) What is your phone? (2) Are you using default launcher, or 3rd-party launcher?

Comment: I'm just a bit puzzled: How did you get into the drawer when there's no launcher?

Answer (score 2):

If the launcher icon is not visible in the application drawer, go to `System Settings > Apps > Running` select the launcher.

From there you can perform your fix.